# spark-submit: where to put the log4j.properties file?

Tags: apache-spark, log4j

I am using Spark 2 from Cloudera, where I have a script `run.sh` that calls `spark2-submit` like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
spark2-submit $SPARK_PARAMS --class $MAIN_CLASS $JAR $PROG_PARAMS
```

The problem now is that I cannot get my Spark program to find my log4j.properties file. Where should I place that file?

The current location for this file is in conf/log4j.properties, but it doesn't seem to be found.

```
run.sh 
conf/
`-- log4j.properties
```

Comment: Did you try to use `--files`?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: What is that?

Comment: `spark2-submit --files` Use `spark2-submit --help` to see the help. I'm guessing that it might be a solution and that's why I have not answered your question and giving you hints.